# Towering limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

**Question:**

$$\lim_{{x,y}\to 0^+} \frac{x^{y^{x}}-x^{y^{2}}}{y^x}.$$

**MyApproach:**

Can this be solved L'Hospitals theorem? My problem is that L'Hospitals can be used when numerator and denominator is differentiated with the same variable but here $x$ and $y$ are both tending to $0$ so I don't think this theorem can be applied here. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: You're right about L'Hôptial's rule.  I think you probably have to attack each of the pieces separately.  I think I'd try writing it as the difference of two fractions first.  Of course, if neither one approaches a limit at (0,0), that may not tell you anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, L'Hopital's rule can be applied here. Actually, the limit does not even exist because by evaluating the limit along the sequences $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,1/n)$ and $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,e^{-n})$, which go to $(0^+,0^+)$ as $n$ goes to infinity, we obtain different results.

As regards $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,1/n)$: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{x_n^{y_n^{x_n}}-x_n^{y_n^{2}}}{y_n^{x_n}}&=
\frac{\exp(\ln(x_n)\exp(x_n\ln(y_n)))-{\exp(y^2_n\ln(x_n))}}{\exp(x_n\ln(y_n))}\\
&\to\frac{\exp(-\infty\cdot e^0)-e^0}{e^0}=\frac{0-1}{1}=-1.
\end{align*}

On the other hand for $(x_n,y_n)=(1/n,e^{-n})$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x_n^{y_n^{x_n}}-x_n^{y_n^{2}}}{y_n^{x_n}}&=
\frac{\exp(\ln(x_n)\exp(x_n\ln(y_n)))-{\exp(y^2_n\ln(x_n))}}{\exp(x_n\ln(y_n))}\\
&\to\frac{\exp(-\infty\cdot e^{-1})-e^0}{e^{-1}}=\frac{0-1}{e^{-1}}=-e.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you write a bit more?I can't understand what are you trying to tell.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer Is it clear now what I am trying to tell you? Any further doubt?

Comment: Yes.it is clear now.